# Do we have a common gallery to show images and PDF?

Tags: jquery, gallery

I have an images as well as pdf files. How to show these two things in one gallery, is there any jquery plugin OR another way to achieve this?. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can display your images with PDF files together in single gallery.

You can use [html5box](https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/) jquery plugin and set your images and PDF files something like this:

```
<a href="images/Toronto_1024.jpg" class="html5lightbox" data-group="mygroup" data-thumbnail="images/Toronto_96.jpg" title="Toronto">Image1</a>
<a href="images/test.pdf" class="html5lightbox" data-group="mygroup" data-thumbnail="images/Sunrise_96.jpg" title="Sunrise">PDF1</a>
<a href="images/test1.pdf" class="html5lightbox" data-group="mygroup"  data-thumbnail="images/Big_Buck_Bunny_1_96.jpg.jpg" data-width="480" data-height="320" title="Big Buck Bunny">PDF2</a>
```

Do not forget to set common data-group="mygroup" for all links to combine all this things in one common gallery.

Hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: Can you provide me any link for demo?

Comment: I have tested the gallery above, it's not working for pdf files. Content is not visible in pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

[html5lightbox](https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/) DOES work for pdf files (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> 'pdf' in main page), in response to a comment (i had no rep to comment yet)